# what is d2k in oracle

Tags: oracle

what is d2k in oracle

Answer (score 2):

It's the Oracle Developer Suite, mainly consisting of Oracle Forms and Oracle Reports.

The 2k is from the shortening of 2000 (Oracle Developer 2000).

More info in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Developer_Suite)